# Breakpoint issues in Chrome while using source maps (gulp-sourcemaps)

Tags: google-chrome, gulp, source-maps, gulp-uglify, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm facing some weird issues with gulp-sourcemaps and gulp-uglify working together, basically, we use the gulp-uglify to minify our code and gulp-sourcemaps to create the source map of the project to be debugged the JS code at the console.

So today, while debugging I noticed Google Chrome seemed to was executing an if statement even I knew the condition didn't retrieve a true value, I had my if like this **if ('string-A' === 'string-B') { image.onerror = null }** So, I added a breakpoint at the onerror assignment and chrome was pausing my code there. A very weird case.

[image: Yo can see the er]

I started debugging so I changed the source code for the minified file, to check if the minified code was causing the issue, this is the block of code minified:

l === i && i !== t ? o ? a.src = n : e(a) : l === n ? e(a) : l === t && **(a.onerror = null)**

I don't see any issues there, I checked with some new breakpoints, and highlighted piece of code is never executed because l === t retrives false as it should do. Then I used again the source file just to verify that the onerror value never changed for the image as I thought, so it seems to be an error with the Chrome core while trying to match the minified file with the source. It seems that Chrome stops at a random place.

Is there a way to avoid these issues? I ask this because it took us a long time to test and actually the output is the same, we just validated it was not an issue in our side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, we had some comments were not removed before from the source code, so It was the reason source and the minified file was not matching.